# How to check operators in Scala match case

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am sending an arithmetic operation like: a + b to my program, inside the program I am reading  each part and set the param variable , x is another constant variable I have and the operator. Operator will be feed into args(1) then based on what I have I wanna perform an action using another program. The following is a part of the  program that I explained:

```
 if (param != 0){
            args(1) match {
                    case + =>val resRDD=sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x + param)
                    case - =>val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x - param)
                    case * =>val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x * param)
                    case / =>val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x / param)
                    case _ => "error"
            }
    }
```

And I get following error:

```
 [error]     ')' expected but identifier found.
 [error]           case * =>val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x * param)
 [error]                                                           ^
```

And when I comment this line out I get whole bunch of error like the following for all operators:

```
[error] case + =>val resRDD=sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x + param)
[error]      ^
[error] case + =>val resRDD=sv.apply(sRDD, x:Float=>x + param)
[error]                                               ^
```

If I use

```
   case "+" => //whatever
```

I will get the following error:

```
   [error]  not fount: type +
```

I don't what is wrong with my program!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error for the second scenario?

Comment: It says (for each one of them is the same) "not found: type +"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all, I was able to solve it as follow:

```
  if (param != 0) {
     args(1) match {
          case "+" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x => x + param):Float => Float)
          case "-" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x => x - param):Float => Float)
          case "*" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x => x * param):Float => Float)
          case "/" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x => x / param):Float => Float)
          case _ => "error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use string in pattern matching instead of operators: `case "+" =>` for example

Comment: I have tried that one as well it's giving the same error!

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose lambda's params in parentheses:

```
if (param != 0) {
  args(1) match {
    case "+" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x: Float) => x + param)
    case "-" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x: Float) => x - param)
    case "*" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x: Float) => x * param)
    case "/" => val resRDD = sv.apply(sRDD, (x: Float) => x / param)
    case _ => "error"
  }
}
```

[Here's the official Tour entry on the anonymous function syntax.](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html)

By the way, according to [Scala Style Guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/) it's better to indent each level with 2 spaces instead of 4.

I would advice you to read [Programming in Scala](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed), which is a great book to start learning Scala (and advance further). It will cover all the basic questions concerning syntax, style and best practices - you'll find it useful.