# How to Check whether input variable is Int in Scala?

Tags: scala

Hi I am reading through input variables from "args" and I want to check whether the input is integer value. I followed [this link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html)

```
    var param=0
    ...
    args(j) match {
                    ...
                    case args(j): Int => param =args(j)
                    ...
            }
```

but it gives me an error:

```
[error] '=>' expected but ':' found.
[error]            case args(j): Int => param =args(j)
```

Can't figure out what is the problem!

Comment: Types are statically determined, `args` is an array of strings. If you want to check if args(0) can be parsed as an integer - do that.

Comment: Yes I am trying args(j) in which "j" is an int variable used to show in which index I am

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 val intRegex = """(\d+)""".r
 val param = args(j) match {
   case intRegex(str) => str.toInt
   case _ => 0 // or some other value, or an exception
 }
```

You might want to use some argument parsing library though.

Or, if you'd like to assign a number of parameters in a single pass:

```
for (arg <- args) {
  arg match {
    case intRegex(arg) => param = arg.toInt
    case p if Files.exists(Paths.get(p)) => path = Paths.get(p)
    case _ => //
}
```

But this is a rather ugly solution. I'd strongly advice you to use some library, e.g. Scopt (https://github.com/scopt/scopt). You might spend some time before you get used to it, but it's for good - you won't be reinventing the wheel next time :)

Comment: Thank you. but I have a question I have another case in this matching that checks whether it's a "Path" so I changed the code to  :  val intRegex = """(\d+)""".r ;  args(j) match {
                        case (Files.exists(Paths.get(args(j))))=> hdfsInput=args(j); 
                        case intRegex(str) => param= str.toInt; 
                        case _ => 0; 
                }
how is param equal to args(j)?

Comment: if I say val param=args(j) match ... then my first case statement becomes wrong because I want to check if it's a patch put it in root variable and if it's an int put it in hdfsInput , how can I handle that part?

Comment: You are correct, it's totally unnecessary to strictly follow my example. I'll update the answer with a couple of variants, check it out later.

Comment: I have posted another question would you please take a look at it (regarding to this program that I am working on ) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220893/how-to-check-operators-in-scala-match-case

Comment: How did you come up with a regex as a solution... Scala's pattern matching is made specifically to do not have to use those or any other complicated identification method.

Comment: @MrBouh I honestly don't know, guess that was way younger

Comment: Downvote because this will crash on a value not within the numeric limits of Int.

Answer (score 8):

```
val isInteger = Try(args(j).toInt).isSuccess
```

Comment: I tried your way like: ".. case Try(args(j).toInt).isSuccess => param=args(j).toInt .." I get this error: " ')' expected but '.' found. " for the part :  Try(args(j).toInt) it points to the "." between args(j) and toInt. Do you know what is the problem ?

Comment: Instead of case Try(...).isSuccess =>, do if (Try(...).isSuccess) ... else 0.

Answer (score 5):

Using scala.util.Try is another possible way.

```
  Try(
    args(j).toInt
  ) {
    case Success(i) => //do something with int i
    case Failure(ex) => //error message
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just don't understand scala's pattern matching yet, I advise you to go look it up again.
Here is a good introduction https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_pattern_matching.htm

```
param = args(j) match {
  case i:Int => i
  case _ => MyDefaultValueOrWhatever
}
```

edit: Fixed typo in the URL

Comment: With a question as old as this one, the OP has probably figured out pattern matching by now and moved on.

Comment: I know, but some new scala programmers might find it helpful. Even more so since it is clearly said that pattern matching is not understood properly here.
I couldn't help myself when I view the other answers, too misleading IMHO

Comment: @MrBouh I appreciate your answer, however, I am no longer a beginner in Scala and understand Scala's pattern!

Comment: @Rubbic of course you are not a beginner anymore, I was talking about actual new scala programmers.
The answer is intended to make new new scala programmers to go see the resource. StackOverflow rules states that we have to answer the question so I can't just say "hey you who is reading this, go check that out".
So please, don't take it for you.

Comment: This would only work if `args: Array[Any]` instead of `args: Array[String]`, right?